# Parse a xml uploaded with camt_parser rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bank

I installed the camt_parser gem in my rails app.
My goal is to upload and parse camt_file (.xml).

It works perfectly when I parse from a local file this way:

```
require 'camt_parser'
require 'camt'
camt = CamtParser::File.parse 'CAMT053_140518.xml'
puts camt.group_header.creation_date_time
camt.statements.each do |statement|
    statement.entries.each do |entry|
        # Access individual entries/bank transfers
     #   puts "->"
     puts entry.description
     puts entry.debit
     p entry.transactions[0].iban
     p entry.transactions[0].transaction_id
     puts entry.transactions[0].debitor.iban
    end
end
```

But when I try to upload it from my view as a file using this code:

```
<%= form_tag '/patient_page/import_camt', :multipart => true do %>
    <label for="file">Upload text File</label> <%= file_field_tag "file" %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

and

the corresponding method:

```
def import_camt
    uploaded_file = params[:file]
    parsed_file = uploaded_file.read
    camt = CamtParser::File.parse uploaded_file
    puts camt.group_header.creation_date_time
    camt.statements.each do |statement|
        statement.entries.each do |entry|

        puts entry.description
        puts entry.debit
        p entry.transactions[0].iban
        p entry.transactions[0].transaction_id
        puts entry.transactions[0].debitor.iban
        end
    end
  end
```

I get the following error

"no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String"
at the line when I try to parse the uploaded file.

Any hints?

Thx!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i changed with to what you said, and it spits this error app/controllers/patient_page_controller.rb:10:in `import_camt'
  Rendering /Users/Djodjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/Djodjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Djodjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb

Comment: and some more lines that I can paste if needed

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks man!

Comment: Could you explain me a bit more into details what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CamtParser::File.parse` is expecting a file path but you are passing an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object.

When you upload a file in rails the file is wrapped in an instance of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`. To access the file itself there is an attribute called `tempfile`.

This will return the `Tempfile` that represents the actual file that is being uploaded. A `Tempfile` has a `path` method which is the path to the file itself so since `CamtParser::File.parse` is expecting a file path it can be called as follows

```
CamtParser::File.parse(uploaded_file.tempfile.path)
```

`CamtParser` also has a `String` class that can parse an appropriate string so you could call this as

```
CamtParser::String.parse(uploaded_file.read)
```

This works because `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` exposes the method `read` which is the same as calling `uploaded_file.tempfile.read`